# Preventing form submit from reloading page

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make my form submit the data without reloading the page itself but currently I am struggling to do so.

Nothing is happening when I click my submit button in the current setup I have. If I remove the `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` then the data will save but the page reloads.

Form HTML

```
<form id="predictionform-1" action="" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()"><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="_footballpool_wpnonce" name="_footballpool_wpnonce" value="f12119edf4"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/play/"><input type="hidden" name="_fp_form_id" value="1"></p><table id="matchinfo-1" class="matchinfo input"><tbody><tr><td class="matchtype" colspan="11">All</td></tr><tr><td class="matchdate" colspan="11">Dec 13, 2016</td></tr><tr id="match-5-1" class="match open" title="match 5">
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td class="score" style="width: 48%; text-align: center;"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="_home_5" value="3" class="prediction"></td>
<td style="width: 4%; text-align: center;"></td>
                    <td class="score" style="width: 48%; text-align: center;"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="_away_5" value="1" class="prediction"></td>
                    <td title="score" class="numeric"><span class="no-score"></span></td>
                                            </tr></tbody></table><div class="buttonblock button-matches form-1"><input type="submit" name="_submit" value="Save"></div><input type="hidden" id="_action_1" name="_fp_action" value="update"></form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
    return false;
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: You will need to use ajax for that. search on google.

Comment: Bind your form with `document.getElementById('predictionform-1').onsubmit = function(event) { event.preventDefault(); }` or better even  use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 1):

Don´t use the HTML attribute onsubmit, it is not a good practice.

But the problem is that you must catch the event and prevent his default behavior, something like this:

```js
var form = document.getElementById("predictionform-1");

function update(){
  console.log("You submited the form!");
}

form.addEventListener("submit", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  update();
  
});
```

```html
<form id="predictionform-1" action="" method="post"><p style="text-align: center;"><input type="hidden" id="_footballpool_wpnonce" name="_footballpool_wpnonce" value="f12119edf4"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/play/"><input type="hidden" name="_fp_form_id" value="1"></p><table id="matchinfo-1" class="matchinfo input"><tbody><tr><td class="matchtype" colspan="11">All</td></tr><tr><td class="matchdate" colspan="11">Dec 13, 2016</td></tr><tr id="match-5-1" class="match open" title="match 5">
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td class="score" style="width: 48%; text-align: center;"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="_home_5" value="3" class="prediction"></td>
<td style="width: 4%; text-align: center;"></td>
                    <td class="score" style="width: 48%; text-align: center;"><input type="text" maxlength="3" name="_away_5" value="1" class="prediction"></td>
                    <td title="score" class="numeric"><span class="no-score"></span></td>
                                            </tr></tbody></table><div class="buttonblock button-matches form-1"><input type="submit" name="_submit" value="Save"></div><input type="hidden" id="_action_1" name="_fp_action" value="update"></form>
```

The form above won´t submit because sandbox mode don´t allow form submission.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That stops the page from being refreshed but the data does not save anymore as a result.

Comment: @DaveAnderson If you want to prevent the form from submiting and you still want to send the data asynchronously what you need to use is called ajax. Check jQuery.ajax() http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Thank you one again Daniel for your helpful input.